# Android studio, BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

So I have a problem with my application. I select item from BottomNavigationView and he switch activity normally, but have a problem to change item selected why remains to home not to new activity item..

code Java main activity:

```
package mediaser.tivvmialive;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://rumblehwk.altervista.org/VideoHome/default.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Archivio.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent2);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

And archivio activity is identic cose

Answer (score 1):

You say that the Archivo activity is equal to MainActivity, so what happens is that when you enter the option R.id.navigation_dashboard it opens the Archivo activity that when it is displayed, shows the first BottomNavigation option but the Activity Archivo and not the MainActivity

To achieve that effect you must use a FragmentLayout

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       app:elevation="6dp"
       android:background="@color/blanco"
       android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
       app:menu="@menu/menu_propietario"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in the MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Fragment fragment;
FrameLayout frameLayout;

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenido);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fr = fragment;

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            pestaña = R.id.inicio;
            fragment = InicioFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            fragment = ArchivoFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            break;
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (fr != null){
        transaction.remove(fr);
    }
    if(fragment != null){
        transaction.replace(R.id.contenido, fragment);
    }
    transaction.commit();

    return true;
  }
}
```

and your ArchiveFragment class like that

```
public class ArchiveFragment extends Fragment {

public ArchiveFragment() {
}

public static ArchiveFragment newInstance() {
    ArchiveFragmentFragment fragment = new ArchiveFragmentFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive, container, false);

    return view;
 }
}
```

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 0):

BottomNavigationView resolved thx, but another problem ... "findViewById error cannot resolve method"
Code home (not main activity).

```
 package mediaser.tivvmialive;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;




public class Home extends Fragment {
    public static Home newInstance() {
        Home fragment = new Home();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        String uriPath2 = "http://rumblehwk.altervista.org/VideoHome/default.mp4";
        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
        mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
        mVideoView2.requestFocus();
        mVideoView2.start();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
    }
}
```